# Invalid configuration error while creating a react app with webpack configuration

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Unable to configure webpack with react

below is error :

Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.entry['main'] should not contain the item '—' twice.
   -> A non-empty array of non-empty strings

I have configured webpack and tried

below is webpack.config.js

```
 const path = require('path');
 const HWP = require('html-webpack-plugin');
 module.exports = {
   entry: path.join(__dirname, '/src/index.js'),
    output: {
    filename: 'build.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist')},
module:{
   rules:[{
       test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
       loader: 'babel-loader'
    }]
  },
  plugins:[
    new HWP(
       {template: path.join(__dirname,'/src/index.html')}
   )
  ]
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just use create-react-app and save yourself from configuring webpack yourself.

Comment: I know create-react-app. I am trying to learn more on webpack.

Comment: Which line of code you have error ?

Comment: I think entry needs to be an array or object. try `entry: { main: path.join(__dirname, '/src/index.js') },`

Comment: onfiguration.entry['main'] should not contain the item '—' twice.

Comment: @VaibhavVishal i tried your answer but still same issue.

Comment: `entry: { main: './src/index.js' },` or just `entry: { main: './index.js' },` try a few different combinations.

Answer (score 2):

I solve this adding "--live-reload false" to my start command.

"scripts": {

> ```
> "ng": "ng",
> "start": "ng serve --live-reload false",
> "build": "ng build",
> "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
> "test": "ng test",
> "build:single-spa:mf-test2": "ng build mf-test2 --prod",
> "serve:single-spa:mf-test2": "ng s --project mf-test2 --disable-host-check --port NaN --live-reload false"   },
> ```

Answer (score 0):

i think this will work

```
 const path = require('path');
 const HWP = require('html-webpack-plugin');
 module.exports = {
   entry: ['./src/index.js'],
    output: {
    filename: 'build.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist')},
module:{
   rules:[{
       test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
       loader: 'babel-loader'
    }]
  },
  plugins:[
    new HWP(
       {template: path.join(__dirname,'src/index.html')}
   )
  ]
}
```

Comment: same issue.--> invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.entry['main'] should not contain the item '—' twice.

Answer (score 0):

changing scripts start command in package.json as below made it working,

```
"start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.js --port 3000",
```